# Applying functions over a list of data frames to get summary values

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe

I have a list of two data frames df1 and df2 (please see below for the data). For each data frame, I am trying to get two summary numbers 1) counts of Pat and Ben and 2) number of occurrences of concordance among columns a and b (0/0 or 1/1) for Pat and Ben. Using dplyr, I can get these numbers individually from the data frames like so  (e.g. for df1 in the list below in `dput(my_list)`:

```
   final_table<-mutate(df1,dam=apply(df1[,c(1:2)],1,function(x)length(grep("1",as.factor(x)))))%>%mutate(tol=apply(df1[,c(1:2)],1,function(x)length(grep("0",as.factor(x)))))%>% mutate(prop.concordant=ifelse(dam==0,1,dam/(dam+tol)))%>%group_by(c)%>%summarise(count=n(),complete_concordance_num=length(which(prop.concordant==1)))
```

which looks like this:

```
> final_table
# A tibble: 2 x 3
      c count complete_concordance_num
  <chr> <int>                    <int>
1   Ben    43                       37
2   Pat    57                       55
```

However, I am having problems implementing this over a list of data frames i.e. df1 and df2 in a list. Either `lapply` or `purrr::map` doesn't seem to work. The hurdle seems to be different column names (column 1 and 2) for each data frame. Really appreciate any clues!

Here is an test list (the actual list contains 500 data frames , each with different names of columns 1 and 2):

```
dput(my_list)     
list(structure(list(a = c("0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", NA, "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", 
"1", NA, "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", 
"1", "1", "1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", 
"1", "0", NA, NA, "0", NA, "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"
), b = c("1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", 
"1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", 
"1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), c = c("Pat", 
"Ben", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", 
"Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", 
"Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", 
"Pat", "Ben", "Pat", "Pat", "Ben", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", 
"Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", 
"Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Ben", "Ben", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", 
"Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Ben", "Pat", "Pat", 
"Pat", "Ben", "Pat", "Ben", "Ben", "Pat", "Ben", "Pat", "Ben", 
"Pat", "Pat", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Pat", 
"Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", 
"Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat"
)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c"), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(x = c("0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", 
    "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", NA, "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", 
    "1", NA, "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", 
    "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", 
    "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", 
    "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", NA, NA, "0", NA, "1", "0", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), y = c("1", "0", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", 
    "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", 
    "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", 
    "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"
    ), c = c("Pat", "Ben", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", 
    "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", 
    "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", 
    "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Pat", "Ben", "Pat", "Pat", "Ben", "Pat", 
    "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Ben", "Ben", 
    "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Ben", "Ben", "Pat", 
    "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", 
    "Ben", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Ben", "Pat", "Ben", "Ben", "Pat", 
    "Ben", "Pat", "Ben", "Pat", "Pat", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", 
    "Ben", "Ben", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", 
    "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", 
    "Pat", "Pat", "Pat")), .Names = c("x", "y", "c"), row.names = c(NA, 
    100L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Comment: There are NA values as well.  In the code, it is not shown how you want to deal it

Comment: @akrun Yes should have mentioned. There are NAs. If the function operates on complete cases that'd be fine. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(my_list, idcol="grp")[,
     dam := Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, function(x) x==0 & !is.na(x))), .SDcols = 2:3
    ][, tol := Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, function(x) x==1 & !is.na(x))), .SDcols = 2:3
     ][, prop.concordant := 1][dam!=0, prop.concordant := dam/(dam + tol)
      ][,.(count = .N, complete_concordance_length = sum(prop.concordant ==1) ) , .(c, grp)]
#     c grp count complete_concordance_length
#1: Pat   1    57                          55
#2: Ben   1    43                          37
#3: Pat   2    57                          52
#4: Ben   2    43                          32
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, this works.. Thanks! However when applying to the entire list  of 500 data frames I am getting the following error: "column or expression 1 of 'by' or 'keyby' is type builtin. Do not quote column names. Usage: DT[,sum(colC),by=list(colA,month(colB))]". The error stems from running the  last bit of code "[,.(count = .N, complete_concordance_length = sum(prop.concordant ==1) ) , .(c, gap)]"  ...rest works great! I haven't used data.table before so this may be something obvious I am missing.

Comment: @thisisrg Could you check whether the dataset columns have the same type

Comment: a sapply(my_list,function(x) x[]) shows that in all the data frames in the list the first two columns are character and the third column is a factor with two levels("Pat", "Ben"). BTW I was able to get the dataframe from the penultimate step of your code and do the grouped operations in dplyr to get what I needed. So I am accepting this answer. But it would be good to figure out what the error means

Comment: @thisisrg  I think the mixed class may have created the problem.  It may be better to have all the datasets to have the same class